# Could Kilgrave be defeated by wearing earplugs/ear defenders?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

In the TV version of Jessica Jones, it seems that Kilgrave could simply be defeated by wearing strong ear protection so that you couldn't hear his commands.

Would this work, or does his power affect your mind directly?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot fulfill an order you cannot understand or that you don't know it's been issued. Which makes us go to why the hell they didn't got a pair of industrial security headphones and kicked his ass on the fourth episode.

Comment: @Bardo Because at the time they still wanted to take him alive. In retrospect they probably should've rejected that idea much sooner.

Comment: I've never found a type of wearable hearing protection that attenuates the sound so much that I can't hear what someone is saying in a quiet room - and I've tried lots of different wearable hearing protection products.

Comment: Just a note: an ear plugs (even the best ones) doesn't completely block the sound, because the air vibration get as well transferred through the skull bones directly to eardrum. Headphones with loud music would work much better as a way to block Killgrave's voice

Comment: What? I can't hear you!

Comment: @rickster [AYE AYE CAPTAIN!](http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2015-07-14-1436902565-6235018-SpongeBob_5.png)!

Comment: @ToddWilcox hearphones with white noise (or heavy metal) will do just fine.

Comment: Just a note, sure this would make you immune to his effects yourself, but he almost always has others around who are not currently wearing earplugs as a contingency plan, or some other way of dealing with a single person immune to his powers, so using this method to "defeat" him is not a given.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, this would work.

In fact, they attempt some version of this a couple of times:

- Part of the  point of the makeshift Kilgrave-prison is that it's soundproofed:

  > **Jessica:** This is a safe house? It looks like a '70s furniture outlet.
  >
  > **Simpson:** The second floor is a decommissioned CDC facility. One of my boys was their investigator, held some patient zeroes here. It has a hermetically sealed room.
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > **Simpson:** It's soundproof, too.
  >
  > <sup>*Jessica Jones* Season 1 Episode 5: "A.K.A. The Sandwich Saved Me"</sup>

  Kilgrave can scream at you until he's blue in the face (and he does), and he can't compel you to do anything
- In the finale, a character walks into a Kilgrave encounter wearing headphones blaring loud music. Despite him shouting numerous commands in their presence, they're only vulnerable when the headphones later fall off

Comment: Would they really need to be *completely* soundproof? Having worn regular in-ear earplugs, I had plenty of times where I had to look at someone and ask them to repeat themselves. Granted, Kilgrave would be talking much more emphatically, but this goes back to the above comment about "you have to know/understand a command has been given".

Comment: Decent in-ear (plug-style) headphones and **LOUD** music might be a better bet.

Comment: @krillgar Hm, that's a fair point. My experience with in-ear earplugs has been largely negative, but if you've had a different experience, they may be more effective than I'm expecting

Comment: I don't know. I thought that the prison worked because the virus that Kilgrave emitted could not escape?

Comment: @Jonah Might have helped, but it wasn't the reason for the hermetically sealed room; they didn't learn about the virus until after they decided to use the room, and after they actually got him into it

Comment: @JasonBaker Head cannon wise JJ could have been aware from her past association that "sharing air" was required to be influenced (ie, she might easily have witnessed him yelling at someone on the far side of a sealed glass window and it not working).  This doesn't require knowledge of the virus, just extrapolation of previous failed control attempts.

Comment: Interesting follow-on question: if a character listens to recordings of Kilgrave's voice through headphones while near him, are they compelled to follow the recorded instructions?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, or else the trick he pulled in the hospital wouldn't have worked.

Comment: jessica seemed to know that the shared airspace was required, as she wasn't concerned with kilgrave exerting control over anyone when he called trish's radio show.

Comment: I don't know that Jessica had narrowed it down to specifically "shared airspace" before we learned about the virus. What she definitely did work out was that physical proximity had something to do with it, since right from the beginning she says that it takes time and distance for the power to wear off.

Comment: Airspace is required to be infected, and then there must be a method to understand and take commands. Kind of two separate things. Pretty simple really.